# A book with True/False questions for abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation, online-resources

This may sound strange but I learn very well using true/false questions. I feel that they really test my understanding of theorems/properties. I also find them quite fun to do.

However, I'm having a very rough time finding them.

Do you know of any books or any sources that contain a good number of these, so that I may test my understanding?

I found this in one of the other posts. This is precisely the kind of thing that I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: Fraleigh's abstract algebra textbook has some true-false questions at the end of each chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted by Gerry in the comments, [A First Course in Abstract Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201763907) by John B. Fraleigh contains some true-false end-of-chapter questions.

There are also the following MSE posts about true-false questions for abstract algebra:

1. [five true or false questions on abstract algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255118)
2. [True or false question about polynomial ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233062)
3. [True/False about ring and integral domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531002)
4. [Abstract algebra true or false answer check](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846719)
5. [(Theoretical Questions) Determine the following statements are true or false.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267672)

I also found the following [True or False Quizlets](http://www.d.umn.edu/~jgallian/TF/) from Joseph Gallian's course webpage for Math5371 at University of Minnesota Duluth.